# Can't connect to Sql Server database with Netbeans

Tags: sql-server, database, netbeans, connection

I'm trying to make a connection database SQL Server 2012 with Netbeans 8.2

Using the connection wizard I select Sql Server 2012 and enter the credentials and fields.

However I get the message that a connection cannot be established.

You can see screenshots of the entered fields: [Full Resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAMIr.png)
[image: image here]

Comment: Did you install this on the box you are running net beans? Can you post the entire error message? And are you really using SQL 2005?

Comment: Name of Driver is SQL 2005(sqljdbc4), Im using SQL 2012, error message "Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Vetura using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (Cannot open database "Vetura" requested by the login. The login failed.)"

Comment: Did you set up an admin account during installation? did you try sa/Password123 or sa and the password of the local admin account for the computer you installed it on?

Comment: I created new login user:lindi pass: *****, I tried sa password123, sa sa, but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an entry for 'Integrated Security' in your database URL. My connection string, which works, is as follows:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\ComputerName:1433;databaseName=DatabaseName;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Change your entry for 'integratedSecurity' to false in your case, if you are using mixed mode authentication, and it should work OK.