# Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver in Netbeans AND MMC could not create snap-in in SSCM

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, sql-server-2012

I m trying to set up the Connection between `***SQL SERVER 2012***`and `***Netbeans Java***`, I was establishing connection with the help/reference of a `youtube` video ***https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwE7vzBIXxs***. My problem is that when I was on the way for connection in java, In customize connection after filling all fields the following error occurs

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS:1434; 
databaseName=URMS using com.mic
```

[You can view it in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXyqX.png)

And when I go for the settings in `***SQL SERVER Configuration Manager***`
When I open it, It shows the following ERROR

```
MMC could not create the snap-in
```

I have provided the second image in comments please go through it

Before this error in 'Sql Server Configuration Manager`, I was working on previous install of`***SQL SERVER 2012***`In that installation 'Sql Server Configuration Manager` was working, But the problem was that under `SQL Server Network Configuration' the protocols was missing for that purpose I reinstall the SQL SERVER 2012 but the problems increased

```
Previous Installation ***SQL SERVER 2012 32 bit*** windows 10 64
New Installation ***SQL SERVER 2012 64 bit*** windows 10 64
```

Please guys help me get me out from these ERRORS.

Comment: [You can view the network configuration manager image][2]


  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oAsh.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the first part of your question is concerned, you could refer to this: [cant-connect-to-sql-server-database-with-netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937983/cant-connect-to-sql-server-database-with-netbeans/43065995#43065995)

Just add `integratedSecurity=true;` to the end of your connection string if you are using Windows Authentication, or false otherwise, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the final answer...
If you do that integratedSecurity= true(for when you use windows auth) or the integraterSecurity= false(for when you use sql server auth) and it still throws a red exception error message thing then all you have to do is go and download the latest jdbc because the older ver. doesnt have that. then when you add it in netbeans and do bla bla it works without the integratedSecurity thing...